# Sql server trigger to .Net call

Tags: .net, sql-server

Whenever a record is inserted or updated in a sql server table, I have to call a third party service which will insert/update their table. What is the most efficient way to do this?

1. SQL server trigger to .Net call (I'm not sure if this is possible... Is it possible to send the id of the record to a .Net application whenever insert/update occurs?)
2. An application which checks continuously for changes in the table using a select statement, get the particular record -> send through service.
3. Something else?

Comment: Is the other database a SQL Server db as well? If so, you could look into Service Broker, a messaging framework for SQL Server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb839489.aspx

Comment: In my opinion Service Broker is the way to go even if the other server isn't SQL Server. You can use a trigger to drop a message in a queue (in the same database), and write a queue processor to do the web service call. Service calls on SQL Server-owned threads is not the way to go.

Comment: @John, @camainc.. thank you for answering.. Could you please provide info/articles on how to access queues in sql server? Also, since i'm not familiar with service broker, do you think the following is a good alternative? Insert the record id's in a separate table on insert/update of the original table->external application checks on this table continuously->deletes the record in this table after processing.

Comment: Never mind. I think, Sql Server Service Broker with External Activation is what I should be looking for.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server 2005 and above, you have the ability to create [CLR Stored Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx), which are stored procedures that run standard .Net code, as opposed to SQL related code. There are some limitations to what it can do, but you could easily create an insert trigger that passes the @@IDENTITY of the new record added to a CLR stored procedure that does the .Net processing you need.

Comment: +1, Its actually surprisingly straight forward to create these, though it does take some server config changes. Calling an external web service may require additional permissions for the account running SQL server.

Comment: Worst possible solution. Inthe first place it assumes only one record, it also uses @@idnetity instead of the inserted tables (and @@identitiy is known to be unreliable). And you do not want triggers to contain a call to a third party service or no records can be changed if it goes down.

Comment: **Nothing** in a trigger should be able to block if a 3rd party system is slow responding.  Trigger should write to message broker queue, queue should then call external system with CLR stored proc if needed.

Answer (score 0):

A long time ago I worked on an application that
for each “data” table

- Had a history table that record all inserts, deletes and changes
- Each 'logical' transaction had a history ID, that could be used to find it’s changes across all the history tables
- The history IDs were ints that increased in value, so a 3rd party system to find all changes since it’s last check by doing a select from XyxHistory where historyId > lastProcessHistoryId
- Trigger were used to update the history tables
- Most of the above was generated using codesmith from the data tables

This allowed many 3rd party systems to be integrated without having to change the main application code.