# Push new row from SQL to vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

I want to get the data that is inserted into a table in at close to real time as I can.

For simplicity, let say i have a table called

```
"DataInput"
```

With the columns:

```
ID, Name, Time
```

What is the easiest way using VB.NET to get the row as soon as it gets inserted into the database?

Polling for a new record every second seems clunky.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're using SqlServer and .NET, you might find this question interesting: [Sql server trigger to .Net call](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5302074/851811).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For Sql Server** - You can use **[Query Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130764%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)**

SQL Server 2005 introduced query notifications, new functionality that allows an application to request a notification from SQL Server when the results of a query change. Query notifications allow programmers to design applications that query the database only when there is a change to information that the application has previously retrieved.

Refer:

[Using Query Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms175110%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

[Working with Query Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130764%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Also, for .Net have a look at:

**[SqlCacheDependency Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.sqlcachedependency%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)**:
On all supported versions of SQL Server (Microsoft SQL Server 7.0, Microsoft SQL Server 2000, and SQL Server 2005) the SqlCacheDependency class monitors a specific SQL Server database table. When the table changes, items associated with the table are removed from the Cache, and a new version of the item is added to the Cache.

Refer:

[Using and Monitoring SQL 2005 Query Notification](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/using-and-monitoring-sql-2005-query-notification/)

Comment: [Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a52dhwx7(v=VS.80).aspx) also an example